# Ext JS: How to get sum of two different JSON store's values?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, formulas, extjs-stores

As you will notice belowe I'm fetching to two different stores through `formulas` and getting `TOTALCOUNT` integer values of those JSONs.

How can I get sum of those two different `stores`?

```
formulas: {
        firstStore: {
            bind: {
                bindTo: '{firstStatStore}',
                deep : true
            },
            get: function (store) {
                var record = store.findRecord(MyApp.Names.CODE, MyApp.Names.TOTALSTAT);
                return record ? record.get(MyApp.Names.TOTALCOUNT) : "-1";
            }
        },

        secondStore: {
            bind: {
                bindTo: '{secondStatStore}',
                deep : true
            },
            get: function (store) {
                var record = store.findRecord(MyApp.Names.CODE, MyApp.Names.TOTALSTAT);
                return record ? record.get(MyApp.Names.TOTALCOUNT) : "-1";
            }
        },

       thirdStore: {
                // Here I need "sum of TOTALCOUNT" from firstStore and secondStore.
       }       
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to formulas the same as you can with anything else:

```
thirdStore: function(get) {
    return get('firstStore') + get('secondStore');
}
```

Also, you should change the return type in your other formulas, not sure why you would return a string there.